# how to update missing records in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-insert, recursive-query, monetdb

i have missing records in a sequence and my current output looks like this

```
|       1882 |   25548860 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548861 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548882 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548883 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548884 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548885 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
                         missing records in between until 2122
|       2122 |   25548860 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548861 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548882 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548883 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548884 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548885 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
```

I want my output to be in below format. Suggest me a sql query that will update the records in monetdb between 1883 to 2121.

```
|       1882 |   25548860 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548861 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548882 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548883 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548884 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1882 |   25548885 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |

|       1883 |   25548860 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1883 |   25548861 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1883 |   25548882 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1883 |   25548883 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1883 |   25548884 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       1883 |   25548885 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
     ........   ..........
     ........   ..........
|       2122 |   25548860 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548861 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548882 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548883 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548884 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
|       2122 |   25548885 |         4 | 30                  | null      |       null |
```

Comment: Do you want to actually insert the extra rows in the table, or just to display them as a result of the query?

Comment: Can you please show the query you are using?

Comment: @TheImpaler i want to insert the records

Comment: @BoilermakerRV i'm just using a basic select statement to query my table where i have missing records from 1883 to 2121. The table follows a trend and gets iterative after 6th row. So, I want to insert records in the desired format as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance the range of missing `id`s, you can use `generate_series()`. Assuming that your table is called `mytable` and has columns `(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)`, you can duplicate the records that have `id` 1882 to fill the gap with the following query:

```
insert into mytable (id, co11, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select value, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from sys.generate_series(1883, 2121, 1)
cross join mytable t
where t.id = 1882
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the schema of your table is something like:

```
create table mytable(id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int);
```

You can fill in the "missing records" with:

```
insert into mytable
select *, 4, 30, null, null 
from sys.generate_series(1884, 2121, 1),
    (select distinct col1 from mytable where id = 1883) as tmp;
```

However, the new records will be appended to the existing records, so if you want to have them returned in the order you showed above, you need an additional order by:

```
select * from mytable order by id, col1;
```